# How do I read UID NFC with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, uid

Is possible read UID NFC on the client side (using javascript, jQuery, AJAX)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited the title of your question to make question more clear, removed technologies that shouldn't have been there. The title was changed to make it easier to find the question

Comment: you can use AJAX to make a request to your backend where the UID NFC would be processed

Comment: @AlexanderM. — Given that the NFC reader is, presumably, built in to an Android Phone running a web browser … how would Ajax help? The backend would be on a different computer with no access at all to the NFC reader.

Comment: @Quentin, well, my guess was incorrect